# Howto enforce object construction on first subscription only?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming

Taking my first steps with Rx I am stuck here:

```
public class DisposableResourceDemo : IDisposable
{
    public DisposableResourceDemo() {
        Console.WriteLine("DisposableResourceDemo constructor.");
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Console.WriteLine("DisposableResourceDemo.Dispose()");
    }

    public void SideEffect() {
        Console.WriteLine("DisposableResourceDemo.SideEffect()");
    }
}

[Test]
public void ShowBehaviourOfRxUsing()
{
    var test = Observable.Using(() =>
        {
             // This should happen exactly once, independent of number of subscriptions,
             // object should be disposed on last subscription disposal or OnCompleted call 
                return new DisposableResourceDemo();
        },
        (dr) =>
        {
            return Observable.Create<string>(
                (IObserver<string> observer) =>
                {
                    dr.SideEffect();
                    var dummySource = Observable.Return<string>("Some Text");

                    return dummySource.Subscribe(observer);
                });
        }).Publish().RefCount();


    Console.WriteLine("before 1st subscription.");
    test.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted in 1st."));
    Console.WriteLine("before 2nd subscription.");
    test.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted in 2nd."));
}
```

To my surprise the code above yields

```
before 1st subscription.
DisposableResourceDemo constructor.
DisposableResourceDemo.SideEffect()
Some Text
OnCompleted in 1st.
DisposableResourceDemo.Dispose()
before 2nd subscription.
--> [happy with missing "Some Text" here]
OnCompleted in 2nd.
--> [unhappy with second instantiation here] 
DisposableResourceDemo constructor.
DisposableResourceDemo.SideEffect()
DisposableResourceDemo.Dispose()
```

Please note that calling Connect() manually after both subscriptions is not what I want here, though then the output is as expected.

Comment: Have you considered using `Lazy<T>`?

Comment: Yeah, but Lazy does not implement IDisposable, so I got stuck with Observable.Using. I also have the impression that the solution is *inside* Rx.

Comment: I guess the answer is - who is rising 'OnComplete' event ? and why 'OnCompleted in 2' come **before** outher Observer (`DisposableResourceDemo`) created. As I see from code inner Observer `dummySource` subscribe to outher Observer `DisposableResourceDemo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you are trying to achieve here. It seems that you want to share the  observable sequence and its related resources. So the standard ways to do this is with the ConnectableObservable types that you get from .Replay() and .Publish() etc

You say you dont want to use .Connect() and instead you use .RefCount() which is very common. However, your sequence completes. You also are using the Extension method Subscribe(...) which will internally create an Auto detaching observer, i.e. when the sequence completes, it will disconnect.

So my question is, should the internal sequence actually complete? 
If the answer is yes, then why would the 2nd subscription get the OnComplete notification...it has happened already, it is in the past. Maybe you do want to replay the OnComplete, in which case maybe .Replay(1) is what you want.
If the answer is no, then you can easily fix this by putting a Concat(Observable.Never<string>()) either before the .Publish() or after the Observable.Return.

Comment: I expected hot observables to be such that if they already completed a new subscription would receive an OnComplete() maybe even an OnError that occured. At least this is the behaviour I'd like to have here: The first subscription obtains all messages, the 2nd one obtains what is left at subscrition time. Is my point clearer now?

Comment: Btw.: @Lee: Your book is great!

Comment: I do not see how Replay might help here, could you please explain?

Comment: `}).Concat(Observable.Never<string>()).Publish().RefCount();` was the solution! Thanks for the hint.